# Collaboration between a Graphic Designer and Expression Blend developer?

Tags: c#, design, visual-studio, collaboration, graphics

I'm new to the programming world and also a little bit confused. My brother would like to work with me on some program. I'm a graphic designer so he asked me for UI and all it's elements. I would really help him as much as it's possible so I have found Expression Blend for Visual Studio. At first it looked great but after few minutes I've started to understand that I totally don't know What to do with my project.

Lets assume that I have already made an Interface. Even made in Blend. Now, how can I give it to him so he could implement the UI? How to export and how to give it to him. For example, He works on separate PC and I need to export the project and give it to him for implementation. I know everything about Graphic Design but nothing about coding. I know that he uses Visual Studio :)

I have been working in a web company so my workflow was very easy. It was only to send well prepared PSD file. With Blend I don't know what's next after the design part is finished.

Comment: **[cross-posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is strictly frowned upon...'")** and closed at TWP: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24083/what-are-your-recommended-workflows-for-collaboration-between-a-graphic-designer and at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661367/what-are-your-recommended-workflows-for-collaboration-between-a-graphic-designer

Comment: ehhh... these are mine. please, read the content first. They have sent me here with the question, so I ask also here.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the designer will work with Blend (in addition to whatever other tools) and the developer will work with a combination of Blend and/or Visual Studio. You'd hand him your Blend project files and XAML. He'd load them up in Visual Studio (or Blend; developers use both) and begin hooking up the interface you developed to the program's business logic.

Note that you can open a Blend project file in Visual Studio and certain Visual Studio project types (WPF, etc.) in Blend. That's what enables the above workflow.

More info: [MSDN: Collaboration with Expression Blend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514663%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow :) Thanks a lot. So as I understand it works almost the same as with common file sharing. I'll try to do my best then :)

Comment: The organizational workflow may be more complex ("all GAs must submit isolated Blend prototypes to the dev staff with accompyaning TPS report w/ cover sheet") and in many organizations the GAs don't use Blend at all despite MS's best wishes. But at root, yes.